# I trying to remove folder/folder name from url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change the URL
**My Url**
     http://localhost/MotoMate/corporate/company/kenstar 
    **My target url will be**
       http://localhost/MotoMate/kenstar

```
**I am using .htacees file:-**

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /MotoMate/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MotoMate/index.php/$1 [L] 
#AuthType Basic 
#require valid-user 
#Allow valid-user 
#Deny from all 
#Allow from env=test_uri 
#Allow from env=live_url 
#Satisfy any Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^corporate/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R] 
RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

But it's not working. not changing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in `/Moto/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /MotoMate/ 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /corporate/company/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule !^corporate/company/ corporate/company/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it's working fine and change name of url But. i m getting erro "404 Page Not Found"